# Fonts not rendering correctly until I change the screen resolution to another resolution and back again

Tags: display, fonts

I've just installed Xubuntu 19.10 on an old Dell Inspiron 545. Unfortunately the fonts are a little fuzzy and the only thing I've found that works is to change the display resolution down and then back up again. This makes the fonts crystal clear.

Adjusting font smoothing etc. makes no difference.